# Check if a particular string is contained in a list of strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to search a string to see if it contains any strings from a list,

```
var s = driver.FindElement(By.Id("list"));
var innerHtml = s.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

`innerHtml` is the string I want to search for a list of strings provided by me, example

```
 var list = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
```

so if say innerHtml contains "One" output Match: One

Comment: What if the HTML contained `one`? What if it contained `Onesimus`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
int result = list.IndexOf(innerHTML);
```

It will return the index of the item with which there is a match, else if not found it would return -1.

If you want a string output, as mentioned in the question, you may do something like:

```
if (result != -1)
    Console.WriteLine(list[result] + " matched.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No match found");
```

Another simple way to do this is:

```
string matchedElement = list.Find(x => x.Equals(innerHTML));
```

This would return the matched element if there is a match, otherwise it would return a null.

See [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: how can I make it return the current string in list rather than -1 or +1?

Comment: @UniversityHelp One simple way to do it is to have an if else block, similar to what I just updated in my answer.

Comment: @UniversityHelp I just updated my answer with another easy way.

Comment: thank you appreciate that :), any idea how I could split a list into 2 columns? I'm currently using

List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines("textfile.txt").ToList();

Comment: which contains a list of strings, but if i add say " Name:ID " is it possible to split the list into columns and search for id? and then use name as output

Comment: @UniversityHelp Your query is still a bit unclear to me but based on my understanding of it. I believe this is what you hope to achieve. See: https://imgur.com/a/ju8QR7p

Comment: @UniversityHelp I would strongly recommend you start another thread/question and post its link in a comment here so I can deliver a more detailed writeup with added space.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with LINQ by applying `Contains` to `innerHtml` for each of the items on the list:

```
var matches = list.Where(item => innerHtml.Contains(item)).ToList();
```

Variable `matches` would contain a subset of strings from the `list` which are matched inside `innerHtml`.

**Note:** This approach does not match at word boundaries, which means that you would find a match of `"One"` when `innerHtml` contains `"Onerous"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var str in list)
{
    if (innerHtml.Contains(str))
    {
        // match found, do your stuff.
    }
}
```

[String.Contains documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to serach Arrray of chars in another list of strings

List WildCard = new() { "*", "%", "?" };
List PlateNo = new() { "13eer", "rt4*444", "45566" };

if (WildCard.Any(x => PlateNo.Any(y => y.Contains(x))))
Console.WriteLine("Plate has wildchar}");